# Change name of file being downloaded

Tags: javascript, angularjs, excel, download

I have this piece of code that exports and HTML table to Excel. My issue is when the file download dialog open, the file name is always "download.xls". Is there a way to change the name of the file?

The Code is here which is called on a button click and the ID of the table is passed through to the exporToExcel Fucntion:

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/gGxNxV

```
var myApp=angular.module("myApp",[]);
myApp.factory('Excel',function($window){
    var uri='data:application/vnd.ms-excel;base64,',
        template='<html xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"><head><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml><x:ExcelWorkbook><x:ExcelWorksheets><x:ExcelWorksheet><x:Name>{worksheet}</x:Name><x:WorksheetOptions><x:DisplayGridlines/></x:WorksheetOptions></x:ExcelWorksheet></x:ExcelWorksheets></x:ExcelWorkbook></xml><![endif]--></head><body><table>{table}</table></body></html>',
        base64=function(s){return $window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(s)));},
        format=function(s,c){return s.replace(/{(\w+)}/g,function(m,p){return c[p];})};
    return {
        tableToExcel:function(tableId,worksheetName){
            var table=$(tableId),
                ctx={worksheet:worksheetName,table:table.html()},
                href=uri+base64(format(template,ctx));
            return href;
        }
    };
})
.controller('MyCtrl',function(Excel,$timeout,$scope){
  $scope.exportToExcel=function(tableId){ // ex: '#my-table'
        var exportHref=Excel.tableToExcel(tableId,'WireWorkbenchDataExport');
        $timeout(function(){location.href=exportHref;},100); // trigger download
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

here is an example which demonstrates Export HTML Table to Excel With Custom File Name: http://www.kubilayerdogan.net/javascript-export-html-table-to-excel-with-custom-file-name/